How to properly infer the Constructor of an object through JSDoc?
I want to make this function that receives a parameter and return its class if object, the parameter itself if function or the legacy object constructor if anything else.
In JavaScript the example below covers the functionality for most cases. But the JSDoc doesn't follow...
export const ParseType = ( Subject ) =>
{
   if ( ( typeof Subject == 'function' ) && ( typeof Subject.prototype == 'object' ) )
   {
      return Subject;
   }
   
   return Object(Subject).constructor;
}

function MyCustomType ()
{
   
}
// JSDoc signature: () => void

const MyCustomInstance = new MyCustomType;
// JSDoc signature: any
// Expecting JSDoc signature: MyCustomType

const MyRetrievedCustomType = ParseType(MyCustomInstance);
// JSDoc signature: any
// Expecting JSDoc signature: typeof MyCustomType

To fix this issue, I can do something like this:

/**
 * @template [Type = InstanceType < typeof Object >]
 * @param { Type } [Subject = Type]
 */
export const ParseType = ( Subject ) =>
{
   let Inferred;
   
   if ( ( typeof Subject == 'function' ) && ( typeof Subject.prototype == 'object' ) )
   {
      Inferred =
      (
         /**
          * @type { Type extends Function & { prototype: {} } ? Type : never }
          */
         ( Subject )
      );
   }
   
   else
   {
      const Instance =
      (
         /**
          * @type { Subject & {} }
          */
         ( Object(Subject) )
      );
      
      Inferred =
      (
         /**
          * @type { Type extends Function & { prototype: {} }
          *          ? never
          *          : Instance extends { constructor: infer Constructor }
          *             ? Constructor
          *             : never
          *       }
          */
         ( Instance.constructor )
      );
   }
   
   return Inferred;
}

/**
 * @constructor
 */
function MyCustomType ()
{
   
}
// JSDoc signature: typeof MyCustomType

const MyCustomInstance = new MyCustomType;
// JSDoc signature: MyCustomType

const MyRetrievedCustomType = ParseType(MyCustomInstance);
// JSDoc signature: Function
// Expected JSDoc signature: typeof MyCustomType
// JavaScript actual value: [Function MyCustomType]

const MyRegrievedStringType = ParseType('MyString');
// JSDoc signature: Function
// Expected JSDoc signature: StringConstructor
// JavaScript actual value: [Function String]

I can't extract the constructor from Instance correctly because JSDoc infers the constructor at ObjectConstructor.constructor which is Function. Oddly enough, when I'm extracting the constructor from Instance, in the casting JSDoc type tag I can test Instance against any class and evaluate as the "hard coded" class...
/**
 * @type { Instance extends MyCustomType ? typeof MyCustomType : never }
 */

Or even chaining like this...
/**
 * @type { Instance extends String ? typeof String : Instance extends BigInt ? typeof BigInt : never : never }
 */

But I can't just keep increasing this chain and hard coding all the classes that could possibly be used in any project that will use this function...

What do you mean by “its class“? What do you mean by “legacy object constructor”? There is no legacy, there are just constructors, and a constructor is the same object returned by object.constructor. It can be a class object (not an instance of the class, but a class object itself) or a constructor function object. Classes are nothing but syntactic sugar around constructors.

What I mean by a class is a proper constructor function. No mystery here. What I mean by "legacy" in JavaScript are all things that are native to JavaScript, in other words, not user defined. I'm using "legacy" because we shoudn't change what's legacy as we shouldn't change native stuff; and I don't know a better term (English is not my mother language). My problem is that I'm having problem inferring the native constructor function of a instance in a parameter (which comes as unknown or any). I have to test the parameter against each and every native class that there is in JavaScript...

Thank you for your answer and clarification. No, you shouldn't have used the word legacy here. I don't know the appropriate term if it even exists, usually, there is no need. Perhaps, “native constructor” makes sense. Unknown or any refers to the name that is present in the code but never was defined with const, let, or var as a variable or a constant. If it appears during runtime (a debugger may show it), it's a bug to be eliminated.

Your comparisons with strings like 'function' are incorrect and unreliable. You can use if (object.constructor == ...) or instanceof.

You have done a lot of weird things, but the problem is much simpler if I understand the first paragraph in your question correctly. Consider this snippet:


const Classify = object => 
    object == null // covers both null and undefined
        ? object : object.constructor;

const A = class {}; // essentially, a constructor, syntactic sugar
const B = function() {}; // the original form of constructor

console.log("{}:", Classify({}));
console.log("[]:", Classify([]));
console.log("undefined:", Classify(undefined));
console.log("null:", Classify(null));
console.log("A:", Classify(A));
console.log("B:", Classify(B));
console.log("Instance of A:", Classify(new A()));
console.log("Instance of B:", Classify(new B()));
console.log("Classify:", Classify(Classify));



For A and B, you also can check object.constructor.name. Also note that A and B themselves (not the constructed instances) are both classified as function, and this is correct: they are essentially the same: as I mentioned, JavaScript classes are nothing but syntactic sugar over constructors and original form of inheritance chains.
Note that the comparison object == null covers both null and undefined objects. To tell null from undefined you would need to use === comparison operator, but you don't need it for your purposes, because you can simply return object in both cases.
Finally, there is another case, the most unpleasant one: some wanna-be-variable (or constant) that was never defined in code. It is just a name that has no sense at all. Important: even though it converts to string as "undefined", it has nothing to do with undefined. It is possible to detect such a situation with typeof, but it makes little to no sense. Such names are absolutely evil and should be 100% eliminated. Therefore, it's better not to check anything, but let go and see the exceptions under the debugger. If you check this situation and work around it, you will get code full of garbage.

I understand your solution. But the function itself is not the problem... The function works just fine as I expect it to. It's the JSDoc that's problematic here. I mean, Using your example, what would the IntelliSense tells that const type = Classify(new A); is? For me it is parsing as const type: any. I want it to be parsed as const type: typeof Object in this specific case. Or const type: typeof Number if instead of new A I used a number (or some object that extends the Number class).

KLASANGUI — I understand it. But your question in your first paragraph clearly stated that you wanted to make the function. The function itself in your code is a problem as it is incorrect, and it reveals to me some misunderstanding on your part. And you did not post a question about JSDoc, you only mentioned that it doesn't follow... I explained how it should be and cannot take responsibility for JSDoc. Maybe it has some defects, so what? Do you want us to fix it?

KLASANGUI — I don't even understand why would you have to pay some attention to JSDoc. Is it your job to fix it?  You may want to spot the defect and stop using it, or you may use something better, or you can fix some of the comments manually. I consider all automatic comments as pure garbage contaminating code. Will you think about it?

Friend, I think you forgot the main point that is the "question" itself, which is "How to properly infer the Constructor of an object through JSDoc?". The JSDoc is very important to this project because it is what makes the development using the package easier by enabling the correct hints in most editors. For example, a string contains the toLowerCase() method, but not number or boolean. So, if the function returns any instead of string, the editor won't give me hints for string methods on the result. The same happens for number, boolean or any other type.

KLASANGUI — You are right, this is your main question. I do understand you have a problem with that. But I doubt anything can help to tame JSDoc, sorry to say so. You are perfectly right about assist tools, they are very convenient. But perhaps you need to choose better tools. I also use stuff like Intellisense or similar software serving through the IDE or programming editor (say, highly recommended VSCode), and they work well, they do give good hints you meant. But I also rely on my own brain...

KLASANGUI — Here is another piece of advice: This is the place where you can submit a JSDoc issue: https://github.com/jsdoc/jsdoc/issues.
Unfortunately, they don't have a Discussion page. Create the simplest possible example showing the issue, and steps to reproduce (check if the same issue is already reported or not), also refer to the present page, and submit it. It would make more sense than any possible workarounds. Please don't think I consider the question on the JSDoc irrelevant. It is a development tool, and you have a very relevant concern.
